# Dispaly JSON response from the server to handle bar templates in Ember CLI

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

**My Json API from Server**

I am getting this API response from server. How do I display the JSON in my template.

```
{
  past_bills: [
    {
      id:1,
      Status: "Success",
      Count: 3,
      Subscribers: [
        {
          SubscriberID: 100168,
          Count: 3,
          Invoices: [
            {
              InvoiceYear: "2014",
              InvoiceMonth: "1",
              Link: "https://invoices.test.com/A6034C05-C9BE-4A1A-9741-1E07B04F47BB/100168_3935_2014_02_invoice.pdf"
            },
            {
              InvoiceYear: "2014",
              InvoiceMonth: "2",
              Link: "https://invoices.test.com/00168/5C00ABAE-524D-4D86-A927-610646CEB56E/100168_4799_2014_03_invoice.pdf"
            },
            {
              InvoiceYear: "2014",
              InvoiceMonth: "3",
              Link: "https://invoices.test.com/100168/9533058F-2348-4D67-A1D3-187BC86CF40F/100168_6054_2014_04_invoice.pdf"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**My Routes**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.store.find('past-bill',params);
  }
});
```

---

**My Template**

```
<table>
{{#each item in model}}
    <tr><td>Hiii</td></tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

---

**My Model File**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    Status: DS.attr(),
    Count: DS.attr(),
    Subscribers: DS.attr()
});
```

I want to display the response json to template. I tried but I am not getting the result in the template.

Comment: is ur model an array? the response is an object. so u may need to loop over model.past_bills

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each item in  model}}
        {{#each sub in item.Subscribers}}
            {{#each invoice in sub.Invoices}}
                <tr role="row">
                <td>{{invoice.InvoiceMonth}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice.InvoiceYear}}</td>
                <td><a {{bind-attr href='invoice.Link'}} target="_blank">View Bill</a> {{!invoice.Link}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```